# What happens when setting object property without setter in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var vehicle = function(){
var type;
var tyre;

this.tellTyres = function(){
  console.log(type + " has " + tyre + " tyres");
};

this.__defineGetter__("type", function(){
  return type;
});
this.__defineSetter__("type", function(val){
  type = val;
});
this.__defineGetter__("tyre", function(){
  return tyre;
});
//   this.__defineSetter__("tyre", function(val){
//     tyre = val;
//   });

};

var car = new vehicle();
car.type = "Car";
car.tyre = 4;

console.log(car.tyre);

car.tellTyres();
```

I was learning about the getter and setter. Then I realized Javascript is not throwing any error while setting the value of `car.tyre` without having its setter method.

What happens to the `car.tyre` property outside the constructor. Where does the value 4 store? Does it override?

Comment: Oh and console.log prints out "undefined". Umm... why so?

Comment: If you are learning then please note that this feature `__defineGetter__` is deprecated, Instead use `Object.defineProperty()`

Comment: The book says introduced in ECMAScript 3.1. Thanks for telling... will explore about `defineProperty()`. Do you have any clue what's up with the `defineSetter` method?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript objects are more like dictionaries than like Java objects. This means that you can set and get an object's properties just by using the property accessor operators `.` and `[]`:

```js
var obj = { foo: 'bar' };
obj.baz = 17;
console.log(obj.foo, obj.baz); // logs '"bar" 17'
```

And that is absolutely fine.

But sometimes, you want to do something whenever someone modifies a property of your object. In these cases, you define a getter or setter function for that property (use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) instead of `defineGetter` and `defineSetter`):

```js
var obj = { foo: 'bar' };
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'baz', {
  get: function () {
    console.log('Someone wants to read the property "baz"!');
    return 34;
  },
  set: function (value) {
    console.log('You are not allowed to modify the property "baz"!');
  }
});

obj.baz = 17; // doesn't work
console.log(obj.foo, obj.baz); // logs '"bar" 34'
```

When you create a `new vehicle()`, you create a new object, on which you can set or read properties. You don't need the getters and setters.

Comment: Thanks. :) At the last line you have written // logs bar 17. It should be 34. Almost confused me until I ran the code. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question asks "what happens without setter" and you provide code with setter. Kidding?